# Registros duplicados al realizar la inserción de un formulario a PHP ¿qué puedo hacer?

Tags: php, mysql

Relleno el formulario, le doy a enviar, voy a mi base de datos y hay un registro con la información que añadí yo y otro en blanco, he tratado de redirigir a otra página para que al darle a enviar no vuelva a cargar la misma página y me cree un registro en blanco, pero sin éxito.

```
<?php

        include("conexion.php");

        $id = 0;
        $name = $_POST["name"];
        $adv_date = $_POST["fecha_aviso"];
        $cons_date = $_POST["fecha_consulta"];
        $observ = $_POST["observaciones"];
        $estado = 0;

        $query = "INSERT INTO tb_avisos(name, fecha_aviso, fecha_consulta, observaciones)
                VALUES('$name', '$adv_date', '$cons_date', '$observ')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conexion));

        if($result == FALSE){
            echo "Wrong query";
        }
        else{
            echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
            echo "<table><tr><td>Código: $id</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_aviso: $adv_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_consulta: $cons_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Observaciones: $observ</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Estado de la consulta: $estado</td> </tr></table>" ;
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        header ("Location: consultaavisos.php");

        ?>
```

[image: formulario_html]
[image: Info_bdd]

Comment: Eso que muestras es tan solo la consulta.  Ya llevas dos preguntas en este sitio, pero aun no te has mirado los enlaces para aprender a [ask] ni has hecho el [tour] para aprender mejor cómo funcionamos. Te recomiendo lo hagas ahora para que aprendas las bases para colgar preguntas y obtengas mejores ayudas, pues si nos facilitas el trabajo seremos más lo que podremos ayudarte.  En este caso deberias colgar el codigo donde haces el redireccionamiento que dices, pues no lo veo. Aprende tambien a crear un [ejemplo básico](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: No supongas nada. Muestra un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable de todo el contexto en que ocurre el problema. Sin eso, no podremos ayudarte. Hablas de redirecciones, pero no muestras ningún código en el que redirecciones, ni siquiera muestras el contexto desde el cual es llamado el código que inserta los registros. Pulsa en [edit] para completar tu pregunta. Aparte de eso, deberías considerar definir una restricción `UNIQUE` en tu tabla para evitar registros duplicados, lo cual no significa dejar de controlar las inserciones a nivel de código.

Comment: ¿Cómo se llama el archivo que contiene el código que nos estás mostrando en la pregunta?

Comment: insertaaviso.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Veo varias cosas en tu código:

- Cuando pasas datos por POST, conviene que verifiques que dichos datos no están vacíos. Haremos esa verificación con el operador de fusión de null (si tu versión de PHP no lo soporta, lo podrás cambiar por operadores ternarios).
- Si piensas redirigir, no tiene sentido intentar mostrar datos aquí... Cuando el código ocurra, te irás a otra página, así que lo propio sería pasar los datos que quieras mostrar a esa otra página.
- Deberías evitar declarar variables a las que no les das ningún uso real, como es `$id`.

Considerando eso, así debería funcionar, aunque como dije, querer mostrar información aquí no tiene ningún sentido. De todos modos, hoy día este tipo de cosas no se hacen con redirecciones, sino usando Ajax desde el cliente, que te permite comunicar con el servidor y actualizar la página del cliente sin necesidad de recargas y redirecciones.

```
<?php

    $id = 0; #¿Para que es esto si nunca cambia de valor?
    /*
       Si tu versión de PHP no soporta operador de fusión de null
       Cambia las siguientes líneas por algo como esto:
       $name=!empty($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : null;
    */
    $name = $_POST["name"] ?? null;
    $adv_date = $_POST["fecha_aviso"] ?? null;
    $cons_date = $_POST["fecha_consulta"] ?? null;
    $observ = $_POST["observaciones"] ?? null;
    $estado = 0;
    if($name && $adv_date && $cons_date && $observ) {
        include("conexion.php");

        $query = "INSERT INTO tb_avisos(name, fecha_aviso, fecha_consulta, observaciones)
            VALUES('$name', '$adv_date', '$cons_date', '$observ')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conexion, $query) or die("Couldn't execute query.".mysqli_error($conexion));

        if(!$result){
            echo "Wrong query";
        }
        else
        {
            /*
               Esto no tiene mucho sentido aquí si piensas redirigir
            */
            echo "Registro guardado<br><br>";
            echo "<table><tr><td>Código: $id</td></tr>";
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_aviso: $adv_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Fecha_consulta: $cons_date</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Observaciones: $observ</td></tr>" ;
            echo "<tr><td>Estado de la consulta: $estado</td> </tr></table>" ;
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        header ("Location: consultaavisos.php");
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Datos incompletos";
        /*
           Decide aquí si hay que redigir a algún sitio
        */
    }

?>
```